# What is the stable version for PHP 5.5.9?

Tags: php, php5

Can I ask what is the stable version for php 5.5.9, I want to add this to my additional php version for wamp, cause I want to run a project that is running on php 5.5.9 in the server.

[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tlgn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "stable" you mean that the PHP version runs best with your Wamp installation with Apache. Thus, the thread-safe version of PHP would be the best choice, as it reliably handles Apache requests without causing any concurrency problems. So "php-5.5.9-Win32-VC11-x64.zip" or "php-5.5.9-Win32-VC11-x86.zip" it is, depending if you have a 64- or 32-bit system.